# Group index from column labeling the last element in each group

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset a data frame.  The data frame is to be broken into subsets, where the last element in each subset has a "TRUE" value in the "bool" column. Consider the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(c(3,1,3,4,1,1,4), rnorm(7))
df <- cbind(df, df[,1] != 1)
names(df) <- c("ind", "var", "bool")
df
#   ind         var  bool
# 1   3  0.02343906  TRUE
# 2   1  0.94786193 FALSE
# 3   3  0.50632766  TRUE
# 4   4  0.24655548  TRUE
# 5   1 -1.58103304 FALSE
# 6   1  0.73999468 FALSE
# 7   4  0.10929906  TRUE
```

Row 1 should be a subset, rows 2 and 3 should be a subset, row 4 a subset and then rows 5 through 7 a subset.  The code I have below works (I can subset on the new column), but I was wondering if there was a more "R" way of doing it.

```
index = 1
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
 {
  if(df$bool[i])
   {df$index[i] = index
    index = index + 1
   }
  else
  {df$index[i] = index
  }
}
df
#   ind         var  bool index
# 1   3  0.02343906  TRUE     1
# 2   1  0.94786193 FALSE     2
# 3   3  0.50632766  TRUE     2
# 4   4  0.24655548  TRUE     3
# 5   1 -1.58103304 FALSE     4
# 6   1  0.73999468 FALSE     4
# 7   4  0.10929906  TRUE     4
```

Comment: Why are rows 2 and 3 a subset when the bool column is FALSE TRUE on those?  Same for 5 through 7 (F F T).

Comment: @RichardScriven `bool` is true for the last element in each group

Comment: what josilber said!  -but they deleted it, and I deleted mine, so -  TRUE represents the end of a group.

Comment: Noted :)  Ultimately, I will be subsetting this data frame by that newly created column,  if the answer split the frame into subsets without the new column, I would have accepted that answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thought I would have would be to use the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) on the `bool` column to get the group indices -- this will increase the index value by 1 every time the `bool` value is `TRUE`:

```
df$index <- cumsum(df$bool)
df
#   ind        var  bool index
# 1   3 -1.0712125  TRUE     1
# 2   1  0.4994369 FALSE     1
# 3   3  2.1335274  TRUE     2
# 4   4 -1.5950432  TRUE     3
# 5   1  0.5919880 FALSE     3
# 6   1  2.7039831 FALSE     3
# 7   4 -1.3526646  TRUE     4
```

This is not quite right because all the observations before the `TRUE` of each group are assigned to the previous group. We can fix that by adding 1 for all the observations with `bool` set to `FALSE`:

```
df$index <- cumsum(df$bool) + !df$bool
df
#   ind        var  bool index
# 1   3 -1.0712125  TRUE     1
# 2   1  0.4994369 FALSE     2
# 3   3  2.1335274  TRUE     2
# 4   4 -1.5950432  TRUE     3
# 5   1  0.5919880 FALSE     4
# 6   1  2.7039831 FALSE     4
# 7   4 -1.3526646  TRUE     4
```

Splitting the data frame into a list of subsets can now be achieved efficiently with `subsets <- split(df, df$index)`.